# Does anyone know why API errors are showing as "unknown"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, label, facebook-insights

When I go to Insights --> Developer --> Activity & Errors and try to look at the "API Activity and Errors" section, the errors are all labeled as "unknown":

[image]

Does anyone know how I can see more detail on the errors being logged or even why they are being labeled as "unknown"?

Comment: I would assume that errors labeled as "unknown" are the ones that return "An unknown error has occurred.". Not the best description. For me it usually occurs when i make incorrect graph requests (typos in params, and so on). My suggestion would be logging the requests your app makes and looking into the ones that return "unknown" error .

Comment: I was thinking that this could be why, but when I checked the errors that were logged on my server for April 8th (which I have a lot of confidence in) I only found two that said "An unknown error has occurred.". However, there were 15 shown in facebook for that date. So the numbers don't add up. Even though I'm pretty sure it's not the problem, I will be looking into it further to endure I didn't miss anything.